# slice3Drgl R plot several slices

Tags: r, plot

My dataset is a 3 dimensional array (30,15,4) representing temperature through the water column at four different depths (0.2 (layer1),0.4(layer2),0.6(layer3),0.8(layer4)). Thus, I am trying to get 3d plots with 4 layers.So far, I have used slice3Drgl function. However, I have realized that in the plots I got, the 2nd and 3rd layer look the same (T data from the 0.4 depth is plotted twice), and the fourth layer (upper layer in plot) shows T data belonging to the 0.6 depth.
This is my code:

```
dd<-array(d$T,dim=c(30,15,4))

x = seq(0.126,3.780, by=0.126)
y=seq(0.125,1.875,by=0.125)
z = seq(0.2,0.8,by=0.2)
grid<-mesh(x,y,z)
colvar<-with(grid,dd)
col=jet.col(100)
slice3Drgl  (x, y, z, xs=NULL, ys=1,zs=c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8),colvar = colvar, col=col, clim = c( -1.392,0),theta = 60,smooth=TRUE,
             colkey(clim = c(-1.392,0),at = do.breaks(c(-1.392,0), 2)))
```

This is the plot I get:

[image]

I have checked the data and its correct, no repeated T data in 2nd and 3rd layers.
In addition when defining zs as:

```
zs<-z[seq(1,length(z),len=4)]
```

The 3d plot improves a bit. I can see the correct T data on 1,2,3 layers. But 4th layer still shows T data corresponding to 0.6 depth, instead to 0.8 depth (the 4th layer).

Hope my question is more or less clear and that someone can give me some useful insight,
there is not too much information about this function in the web unfortunately.

Thanks in advance,

Best,
Amaia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error originates with zs parameter for which package document provide no information. Here is a work around that I have used in the past:

```
    dt<-seq(0.01,27, by=0.01)
    dd<-array(dt,dim=c(30,15,5))
    x = seq(0.126,3.780, by=0.126)
    y=seq(0.125,1.875,by=0.125)
    z = seq(0.2,1.0,by=0.2)
    grid<-mesh(x,y,z)
    colvar<-with(grid,dd)
    col=jet2.col(100)
    slice3Drgl  (x, y, z, xs=NULL, ys=NULL,zs=z,zlim=c(0.2,0.8),colvar = colvar, col=col, clim = c(0,18),theta = 60,smooth=FALSE,
         colkey(clim = c(0,18),at = do.breaks(c(0,18), 2)))
```

Basically all you need is add a dummy z layer into the data and then ignore it during the plotting by setting the zlim.

I hope this helps.